# Two Domains for a Gunicorn.service

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I got one domain (domain.com) and one sub domain (subdomain.domain.com) each running Django with Gunicorn and Nginx.

My question is how do I setup Gunicorn.service to include the two domains.

Right ow I have

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=usr
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/usr/myproject
ExecStart=/home/usr/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile -     --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/rc/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How do I add the second project that is for the subdomain.domain.com

Comment: You need two instances of gunicorn, and therefore two .service files.

Comment: @DanielRoseman can the two sites share the same socket?

Comment: Are they actually two different websites? If so no, and there is no reason to make them.

Comment: @DanielRoseman no one is a subdomain of another  as written in the question. So I guess they can use same socket.

Comment: But that isn't the point. The point is that one socket corresponds to one wsgi file. If your subdomain is serving a separate Django site via a separate wsgi file, it needs a separate socket and a separate gunicorn instance.